# Stack Exchange app crashes when coming back from Google Chrome on ios

Tags: bug, status-norepro, ios-app

When I click on a link in the Stack Exchange app it opens it in chrome which then has a linky in the top left to go back to the stack exchange app.

When I do that, the app opens for a second and then crashes.

I clicked on the link to chat message: [image: link to chat]

Then clicked link on top left chrome:
[image: link in chrome]

Comment: Can't reproduce here. Can you provide more specific steps? What link on what part of the app?

Comment: I clicked on the Chrome link to open this question in the browser and couldn't replicate. It opens in a completely new tab without the "special" back button that returns to the app. (iOS 8.1, latest version of SE and Chrome)

Comment: @ArieLitovsky a careers link

Comment: Also chat message @ArieLitovsky I updated the question

Comment: @NateBarbettini updated the question

Comment: What version of the app? Beta or public? With the beta app it doesn't crash when getting back from Chrome.

Comment: @ShadowWizard public app.

Comment: The beta app has not worked for me in a while... It always crashes when I try to go into it

Comment: So better add this to the question, many still use the beta only. As for beta crashing, maybe it's because you have both. Try removing the public first.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I only installed the public one bc my beta one stopped working.

Comment: When opening Chrome, I no longer see this button in iOS 9.